# drive c: and drive d: are on a partitioned 1tb disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

Everything was working fine for years like that until lately the system started dropping drive d:  When I ran pctools it shows drive F: as the partition with C: yet drive F: is a 1tbyte drive by itself.  It seems like drive D: was having I/O issues.  I want to change out the drive that has c and d together with a new drive, but I don't know which drive it physically is on the computer.  How can I tell?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7, click on Start and type Computer Management and click on Computer Management (or click Start -- Run -- click compmgmt.msc -- OK).

[image: Computer Management]

Under Computer Management (Local) -- Storage is Disk Management. Click on that. You should then be able to see which drive letter/partition sits on what drive (if you have multiple disks). You could right-click one of the partitions and change drive letter, if you so desire.

[image]

Comment: Shortcut: just type `diskmgmt.msc` instead of `compmgmt.msc`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear as wether you have a 1tb disk with two partitions or two 1tb disks with one partition each...

The easiest way on windows to see drives and partitions is to use the computer management. Go to Start->Run or press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type compmgmt.msc

Navigate the left tree to the "Disk manager", it will show you all your volumes on the left upper panel, and all the drives and partitions righ below it (wether they are accesible to windows or not)

You can even delete partitions, change or add another drive letter to a volume, etc.

If you prefer command line you can accomplish the same thing with diskpart.exe

```
C:\>diskpart
Microsoft DiskPart version 5.1.3565

Copyright (C) 1999-2003 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: testvm1

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status      Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  ----------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online        10 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             10 GB    32 KB

DISKPART> select partition 1

Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D   VBOXADDITIO  CDFS   CD-ROM        48 MB
* Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition     10 GB  Healthy    System

DISKPART>
```

Comment: @zfus beat me to the answer because I was googling how to use the kbd tag. +1 for using images!